# Using RxJS to display a loading indicator and handling timing with the merge operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following minimal example that demonstrates the problem I am facing, where `episode` is fed a value from the UI and `getEpisodeTitleFromApi` is a long running observable that emits a string.

In the situation where `episode` is null or greater than 6, `result$` emits an empty string immediately to handle invalid or empty input.

The intent of `loading$` should be pretty clear.

```
episode = new Subject<number>();

result$ = this.episode.pipe(
  switchMap(episode => !episode || episode > 6 ? of('') : getEpisodeTitleFromApi(episode)),
  share()
);

loading$ = merge(
  this.result$.pipe(mapTo(false)),
  this.episode.pipe(mapTo(true))
);
```

The problem is, when `episode` is null or greater than 6 and emits right away, `loading$` emits false and then true.

How can I wire up the `loading$` observable to emit in the correct order or achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your result not to run synchronus you can use the observeOn and set the execution on the macro task via observeOn(asyncScheduler) - [RxJS - Scheduler][1]

```
const episode = new Subject<number>();

const result$ = episode.pipe(
  switchMap(episode => of('')),
  observeOn(asyncScheduler)
);

const loading$ = merge(
  result$.pipe(mapTo(false)),
  episode.pipe(mapTo(true))
);

loading$.subscribe(console.error);

episode.next(1);

Output: true, false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
loading$ = combineLatest(
    this.results$,
    this.episode,
).pipe(
   map(([result, episode]) => !result || episode) // show loading if result is falsy or episode
);
```

You might have to use the `startWith` operator to start each observable maybe with default values. The problem is that `episode` is a subject and it will always have a value so it is difficult to turn off since `combineLatest` always has the latest values of each observable in the argument. But something like that should set you in the right direction.